# Why would a HR still ask when I can start work though I have already stated in my resume?

Tags: recruitment, human-resources, phone, pre-screening

Some context: I applied for a temp technician job (stated to be a 3 months job) recently. Though the role was stated to prefer people who can start immediately, I just submitted my resume, having a leap of hope that I might have a chance to work for that company. In my resume I stated that I can only start working from May 2021, the reason being I am still an undergraduate and May-Aug is the only time I can work. When the HR called me, she sounded as if she has not seen my resume/profile and was like "I don't understand why you can only start working in May?". Is it a usual sight for HR to just call applicants without screening their profiles/resume first?

Comment: This happens frequently. Keep in mind that first pass resume screeners often scan dozens if not hundreds of resumes a day for a large number of different roles. Misunderstandings happen a lot.

Comment: This is common, since such data may change during the review process. Depending on your individual agreements, passing a certain deadline (end of the quarter, end of the month ...) may cause the start-date to change. That's why it is often double-checked. Nothing to worry about :)

Comment: Probably didn't read it and commit it to memory. Lots of resumes to go through, and no one reads them word for word let alone memorizes them in that fashion.

Comment: Honestly, it seems like she did you a favor by calling to confirm your availability. The alternative would be to reject your candidacy out of hand because you're unavailable; this at least gave you a chance to explain your situation and see if the company can still accommodate it, and for the company to explain their needs and for you to see if you can start earlier. You might be better off looking for internships or positions explicitly advertised as summer jobs though.

Comment: It's also possible she missed it because that's not something that's normally in a resume

Comment: Also, it should be noted that applying for a temporary 3 months job 2+ months in advance is extremely unusual unless you're a student or a teacher or an executive, or unless you're in a country where it's customary to give 2+ months of advanced notice. And if I were a recruiter, I would be curious about that.

Comment: Not surprisingly, people change their expectations, situations change, so it is not unusual that a potential employer might ask to double check the situation.

Comment: How did HR know you couldn't start until May if they didn't read your resume? Did you also indicate your start date on an application?

Comment: I guess I'm not getting an answer to my previous comment so I'll just say that it sounds like the HR person **did** read your resume and didn't understand your reasoning. Lots of people work while working on their undergraduate degree so it's possible they were looking for further explanation (unusually heavy course load, weird hours for your classes, etc.).

Comment: I wasn't in HR, but I was a hiring manager, and I can tell you that other than skills and experience, we don't read much of your resume, especially when we have 2 weeks to fill a role and have to weed the top 10 applicants for in-person (or videoconference, these days) interviews, after doing ~50 phone interviews, after viewing hundreds of resumes. I've since left that job and during the recruiting and interviewing process of the new one I explicitly said "I cannot start before Jan 1" and had to explain 9 times I could not start on Dec 16 like they wanted. It happens. Just be polite, yet firm.

Comment: @BSMP Yup I did include my earliest start date in the resume. :)

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your input! :)

Answer (score 115):

I wouldn't see it as a red flag.

They might have missed it in the resume, people don't spend a long time reviewing these and could have looked more into the skills/experience section, depends on how clear it was from a quick skim through.

It also could be that one person reviews submissions and shortlists candidates, then a different person is responsible for contacting people. The second person would potentially go by contact details instead of reading the resume again at length.

For some candidates, it could be that circumstances changed since submitting an application, so confirming the possible start date is a very frequent question. Given starting date is potentially flexible depending on the circumstances, and it allows the company to assess this.

Comment: I've had three candidates in the *last year* that gave starting dates weeks earlier than what they had written in their resume and that one had even mentioned in his cover letter...

Comment: "What's your notice period" and "When are you able to start work" may be asked as though they mean the same, but they're very different questions.  HR may be (reasonably) checking which they're having answered

Comment: @DonFusili I sometimes write say next month or 2 weeks to take a short break, but during interview if the interviewer seems to be constrained by time, when they ask about this, I will cut that break to increase the chance of getting hired no matter how little it will affect it, if I really need or like that possible job

Answer (score 30):

Why would they ask? If you stated you can work May to August, and they need someone to start mid April, it is obvious that they would ask you if you could possibly start two weeks earlier. It is the old principle "if you don't ask, you won't get". It's fine to say "no". If they have five new employees arriving on 1st of May, they'd ask everyone, and there is a good chance that one out of the five can start earlier. If they don't ask, they won't find anyone.

Comment: There is also a chance your situation has changed since you authored the resume.  As been pointed out if they need somebody immediately, and they feel you are a good fit, then they have nothing to lose by asking if you can start earlier than when you indicated.  It's also possible that person who asked, does not have your resume, many companies "rack and stack" resumes then candidates resumes might never be seen again.

Answer (score 12):

HR Doesn't know the specifics of your own situation.

While they may be interested in you as a candidate from the details of your resume and your interview, it's possible that *you* have forgotten that your preferred start date is on your resume - after all, I assume this isn't the only job you've applied to, and you may forget that you've listed a start date there, or it may have changed over time.

By asking you to confirm the start date, they are hedging their bets and making sure you personally commit to a date that you know will work for you - and give you a chance to update it in case the 'given' date isn't appropriate anymore.

Answer (score 11):

Anecdotally, I have had two jobs where I provided a very clear start date and subsequently had HR ask if I could start earlier.

On one occasion my new boss would be on vacation for my first 2 weeks and I was asked if I was available to start 3 days early so he could get on-boarding kicked-off and bring me up to speed before he left.

On the other occasion there was a specific (and useful) week-long training for the team they wanted me to attend 2 weeks before the start date I had provided.

I was able (and happy) to accommodate both requests, so it was worthwhile for HR to ask, despite my original availability declaration..

Comment: The same thing happened to me. A project was scheduled to start two weeks prior to my stated starting date, so I joined earlier and was immediately staffed to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, why assume HR read all the document?

But seriously, HR do ask as they may need someone to start asap due to a planning change (or error or failure), and if you were just having an extended break they could get you.

Since it seems it was clear from your CV when exactly you were available it may mean HR was working from a standard list of questions.

Comment: Your answer might be better-received without the joke; I suspect that's where your downvotes are coming from.

Comment: @DanHenderson was told to me by an HR person no less....

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. I know that I would forget the contents of anyone's resume as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the other answers, there is also the negotiation/haggling part.

In the EU (broadly speaking) you have 3 months of notice. Many companies will still ask you  whether you could try to negotiate a shorter notice. This is possible and ultimately depends on how much you are needed during the notice period (to pass on the lknowledge or do minimal work), and how much you are a liability.

Answer (score 0):

It's not what they said, it's how they said it:

> I don't understand why you can only start working in May?

The above statement is confrontational an borderline demeaning. My knee-jerk reaction would be "I think your lack of understanding stems from your lack of reading my resume" but that's obviously not constructive...

To me it signals that the HR person disagrees that May is the earliest you can start work. The other possibility is they feel disrespected that you applied for a position which prefers people who can start work immediately.

Now it might be some sort of language barrier or maybe the HR person was having a bad day or maybe they were on a power trip and assumed they could do no wrong.

At any rate, how you handle the situation is what's most important. I hope you responded with something along the lines of:

> My apologies, in my resume I mentioned that I have classes up until May. I understand that you prefer people who can start working immediately and I am really interested in this position but I cannot cut my studies short.

---

What the HR person should have said is:

> It looks like you cannot start work until May, I'd like to find out more. Do you have some time to talk?

Answer (score -2):

**A resume is not a contract**

A contract of employment requires a clear offer and a clear acceptance affirmed by both parties in writing.*

If a clear starting date is not agreed, they can't hold you to it and you can't hold them to it. **It is to your benefit** to get everything in writing, including remuneration and the nature of your duties. Also you should ask for details of any benefits such as health insurance or pension contributions that you negotiated in the interview.  Sloppy contracts result in sloppy lawsuits as you will know if you have ever watched Judge Judy!

---

*Verbal/spoken contracts are possible but they are usually very difficult to prove. Any contract involving substantial worth should be in writing.

Comment: I'd be interested to know why this was downvoted. Is anything I said factually incorrect?

Answer (score -2):

In my industry it's nothing special to get a 100+ applicants over the course of a weekend. These will be screened and the good ones will be forwarded to HR/Recruiting to set up an interview.
So HR is only responsible for setting meetings up and the mony side and the departments choose the people they want. You can't expect HR to be a specialist in all jobs and since they have a lot of other things to do, why should they bother reading them at all?